# It was not possible to run: dotnet run in visual studio code (macOS)

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-code, sdk

I have installed:

```
Host (useful for support):
  Version: 6.0.1
  Commit:  3a25a7f1cc

.NET SDKs installed:
  No SDKs were found.

.NET runtimes installed:
  Microsoft.NETCore.App 6.0.1 [/usr/local/share/dotnet/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]
```

but, when I run: `dotnet run` show this message ->

> Could not execute because the application was not found or a
> compatible .NET SDK is not installed. Possible reasons for this
> include:   * You intended to execute a .NET program:
> The application 'run' does not exist.   * You intended to execute a .NET SDK command:
> It was not possible to find any installed .NET SDKs.
> Install a .NET SDK from:
> https://aka.ms/dotnet-download

if you have any suggestion how to fix it and run API? Best!

Comment: read the message and do what you are told: **Install a .NET SDK**

Answer (score 1):

It's a common cause of confusion that the `dotnet run` command needs an SDK to work. `dotnet run`, unlike what the name might suggest, is a command for developers working on their applications. It *rebuilds* and runs their application, during a development phase.

If you already have a .NET application built (or published as it's technically called) and you just want to run it, you should use this style of command: `dotnet /path/to/your.dll`. That is, just run `dotnet` against the main dll of the application.

Answer (score 0):

I found issue and fix it. it works for me now. just install dotnet-sdk-yourversion.

```
brew tap isen-ng/dotnet-sdk-versions
brew install --cask dotnet-sdk2-2-100

dotnet --list-sdks
```

You can find it here: https://github.com/isen-ng/homebrew-dotnet-sdk-versions